# WKWebView Connection with Wallet?

Tags: ios, iphone, qr-code, wkwebview, wallet

Is it possible to send a QR code from a WKWebView based iPhone application to iPhone wallet?

I tried to find questions and answers on Google, but I didn't find any answers or solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to compile and sign a pass bundle (for security this should be done on a server, not in the app), download the bundle to your app, and then invoke the `PKAddPassesViewController` to add the pass to the user's wallet.

There's very comprehensive documentation available [here](https://developer.apple.com/wallet/), or you could use a service provider to handle the server side pass creation and management.